# 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, binary, hex

I'm trying to decode hex string to binary values. 
I found this below command on internet to get it done,

```
string_bin = string_1.decode('hex')
```

but I got error saying

```
'str' object has no attrubute 'decode'
```

I'm using python v3.4.1

Answer (score 14):

You cannot decode string objects; they are *already* decoded. You'll have to use a different method.

You can use the [`codecs.decode()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.decode) to apply `hex` as a codec:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.decode('ab', 'hex')
b'\xab'
```

This applies a [*Binary transform*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#binary-transforms) codec; it is the equivalent of using the [`base64.b16decode()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b16decode), with the input string converted to uppercase:

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b16decode('AB')
b'\xab'
```

You can also use the [`binascii.unhexlify()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) to 'decode' a sequence of hex digits to bytes:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.unhexlify('ab')
b'\xab'
```

Either way, you'll get a `bytes` object.

Comment: >>> s = '1bcd67879034'
>>> codecs.decode(s, 'hex')
b'\x1b\xcdg\x87\x904'
>>> ################### this is not expected result: but expected "  b'\x1b\xcd\x67\x87\x90\x34'  "  ## what I'm I missing?

Comment: @rahookds: that looks correct. Note that a bytes literal representation only uses `\xhh` escape sequences for *non-printable* bytes. `34` is the hex ASCII codepoint for the `'4'` character, for example. `67` is `'g'`.

Comment: yep! so, how do I see what I'm looking for? ;-)

Comment: @rahookds: what are you looking for? You *have* the bytes from the hex values.

Comment: I'm looking for binary(hex) value output like b'\x1b\xcd\x67\x87\x90\x34' .

Comment: @rahookds: you already had hexadecimal numbers. This is the bytes values for those hex digits. Their representation is *just that*, a representation. The actual bytes are all there as integer values in a sequence. What problem exactly are you trying to solve here? If you wanted a fully hex output, why not use the original hex digits?

Comment: I wanted to send those hex string('1234567890abcd') to uart. on the other end device expects hex(binary ) values from uart not hex string.

Comment: @rahookds that doesn't tell me anything.  Any documentation you can point me to?

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`binascii`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html):

```
import binascii

binary_string = binascii.unhexlify(hex_string)
```

Comment: Should it be `binascii.hexlify`?